# How to cause an Ubuntu Touch device to vibrate?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I'm toying with my first Ubuntu Touch app and am trying to enable the phone's internal, umm, "vibrator."  How can I go about doing this?

Any pointers on how to do this in either C++, JavaScript, or Go would be much-appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The website says you can do it with an API call to cordova(html5 abstraction layer), so it has to be an exposed api somewhere https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/html5/sdk-14.04/org.apache.cordova.vibration/

Answer (score 0):

Its a module of hapticfeedback, so use:

```
Project "Vibrator"
// Code by VictarionMagne

//if used in openstore remember to mark apropriotly
//ye i camt spell
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtFeedback 5.0
Item {
 property bool isOn:true    
    HapticsEffect{
                id:rumble
                attackIntensity:1.0
                attackTime:500
                intensity:5.0
                duration:1000
                fadeTime:1000
                fadeIntensity:1.0
                }


    id: rootItem
    anchors.fill: parent

    Rectangle{
        id:hh
        color:"red"
        width:600
        height:600
        visible:true
        Button{
            height:100
            width:100
            id:big
            text:"1 wave"
            x:0
            y:0



            onClicked:{
                if (isOn==true){
                rumble.start();}
                else rumble.stop();
                }
            Button{
                x:200

                width:100
                height:100

              text:"toggle"


                onClicked:{
                    if(isOn == true){
                    isOn= false
                        rumble.stop();
                    rumble.duration =10
                        }

                    else isOn=true
                    rumble.duration = 100000
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```